# ARC and none-ARC codes co-work together, unexpected behavior cases on iOS

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, autorelease

Dues to my iOS project is so big and many teams involved in, some modules are written by ARC and others not, on theory the two technologies should co-work well.

In fact it is true for 98% cases, unexpected behaviors will occur for rare ones, especially ARC managed pointer works with autorelease none-arc ones.

See following code, billWebPageVC will release itself along with `@autoreleasepool`, not sure how does iOS work with it? Anyone who has experience on this topic please share and discuss together, thanks in advance.

PS:
Class UPBillWebPageViewController and UPWebData are all ARC, but the viewcontroller which pushes it is none-arc.

```
UPWebData * webData = [[[UPWebData alloc] initWithLaunchType:ELaunchTypeLocalMerchant poiData:_favorMechModel.data[indexPath.row]] autorelease];

UPBillWebPageViewController* billWebPageVC = [[[UPBillWebPageViewController alloc] initWithWebData:webData] autorelease];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:billWebPageVC animated:YES];
```

Comment: Do you mean your app crashes here ? Sorry, I didn't get the point of "billWebPageVC will release itself along with @autoreleasepool" .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Memory management in Cocoa is local. The rules you are supposed to follow in Manual memory management guarantee a standard set of invariants for memory management of objects passed across functions, so to write correct memory management in a function, you only need to care about what the function does inside, and not what any other function does. Automatic Reference Counting (ARC) is simply a compile-time mechanism that automates these rules.

As long as a function is compiled to correctly follow these rules, it makes no difference at runtime to outside code whether it was written with MRC or ARC. Functions written in MRC and ARC should have no problem interacting with each other, because they follow the same set of rules, and never assume that any other function is written in MRC or ARC.

The code you show is in MRC. It looks fine as is and doesn't seem to violate any memory management rules. It is completely irrelevant whether the code it calls is written in MRC or ARC (it could even have been compiled by someone else and you may not even know how they compiled it).

Comment: Thanks. How autorelease implemented by ARC?

Comment: @jianhua: I don't really understand what you mean. The autorelease pool is a runtime mechanism, while ARC is a compile-time mechanism. ARC can retain, release, or autorelease things as it sees fit according to its rules.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add Non-arcs classes in your arc projects, you should add compiler flags in project  settings/build phases `-fno-objc-arc`

Comment: Surely if he had not done that the compiler would be barfing when it saw `release`, `retain`, and `autorelease` keywords?